# Recursive function to move a specific key in a multidimensional array to the bottom of his level

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for a php (sort?)function which move a specific key (`'current_files'`) to the bottom of its array level.

I have sth like that:

```
[A] => [
     [current_files] => [
           [0] => ...
           [1] => ...  
     ]
     [D] => [
          [G] => [...]   
          [current_files] => [...]
          [B] => [...]
     ]
]
[current_files] => [...]
[K] => [...]
```

I need this:

```
[A] => [
     [D] => [
          [G] => [...]   
          [B] => [...]
          [current_files] => [...]
     ]
     [current_files] => [
           [0] => ...
           [1] => ...  
     ]
]
[K] => [...]
[current_files] => [...]
```

I know that i need a recursive function like arr_multisort but i dont understand it -_-

Comment: you mean a built-in function that does your special business logic for your sorting? obviously there is none, figure it out first on how would you sort your array (the criteria) and start coding

Comment: can you give me some tips?

Comment: What is the actual problem with keeping it the way it is?

Comment: @Andreas that could be asked of 75% of Stack overflow questions.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Yes. And most of the times there is no good reason, and you help OP with finding a much more optimized solution

Comment: @Andreas I'm well aware of the XY problem.  75% of stack overflow questions are not one, and yet seem to draw the same "why do you want to" response.  Usually because the person responding doesn't know how to answer the question and so seeks to change it into one they can answer.

Comment: @PhilipCouling what?

Comment: @Andreas what did you not understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172210/discussion-between-andreas-and-philip-couling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

**Written a common function just call that function to move down any key by passing the specific key as argument.**

```
function sortArrayByKey(&$array, $search_key) {
    $searched_key_arr = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => &$values) {
        if (array_key_exists($search_key, $values)) {
            sortArrayByKey($values, $search_key);
        } else if ($k == $search_key) {
            $searched_key_arr[$k] = $values;
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    if (!empty($searched_key_arr)) {
        foreach ($searched_key_arr as $key => $val) {
            $array[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$arr = $this->sortArrayByKey($data, 'current_files'); //$data is your input array
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to remove the key from the original array and push it to the end.

like this :

```
$keyToMove = 'current_files';
if (array_key_exists($keyToMove, $arrayToSort)) {
    $tmp = $arrayToSort[$keyToMove]; // extract the key to move
    unset($arrayToSort[$keyToMove]); // unset the key from the array
    $arrayToSort[$keyToMove] = $tmp; // add the saved data in the end
}
```

Then if you have a multidimentionnal array to "sort" you will have to run this recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Well seeing as you already know the key of the item you want to move, things can be pretty simple with a recursive function. You use the '&' simple to pass the array in as reference.

```
function moveCurrentFiles(&$array) {
    //first move current_files to the end of the array
    if (isset($array["current_files"])) {
        $currentFiles = $array["current_files"];
        //unset then reset value to "move" it to the end
        unset($array["current_files"]);
        $array["current_files"] = $currentFiles;
    }

    //loop through array items to check if any of them are arrays
    foreach($array as &$value) {
         if (is_array($value)) {
             //recursively call this function on that array
             moveCurrentFiles($value);
         }
    }
}
```